# Using PHP to query a MDB file, and return JSON

Tags: php, json, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access Database, and I am trying to query the table using PHP, and output valid JSON. I have an equivalent code for a MSSQL database, am I am trying to make my code do the same thing, but just for the Access database.

Here is the MSSQL code

```
$myServer = "server";
$myDB = "db";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect ($myServer, array('Database'=>$myDB));

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM db.dbo.table";

$data = sqlsrv_query ($conn, $sql);

$result = array();   

do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($data, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;   
    }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($data));

$json = json_encode ($result);

sqlsrv_free_stmt ($data);
sqlsrv_close ($conn);
```

Here is what I tried for the MDB file

```
$dbName = "/filename.mdb";

if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}

$db = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName", $user, $password);

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM cemetery";

$data = $db->query($sql); // I'm getting an error here
$result = array();   

// Not sure what do do for this part...
do {
    while ($row = fetch($data, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;   
    }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($data));

$json = json_encode ($result);
```

I kind of followed this to try to connect to the database: http://phpmaster.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/

Currently this is giving me a 500 Internal Server Error. I'm expecting a string such as this to be saved in the variable `$json`

```
[
    {
        "col1":"col value",
        "col2":"col value",
        "col3":"col value",
    },
    {
        "col1":"col value",
        "col2":"col value",
        "col3":"col value",
    },
    {
        etc...
    }
]
```

Can someone help me port the MSSQL code I have above so I can use it with an MDB database? Thanks for the help!

---

EDIT: I'm commenting out the lines one by one, and it throws me the 500 error at the line `$data = $db->query($sql);`. I looked in the error log, and I'm getting the error `Call to a member function query() on a non-object`. I already have the line `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll` uncommented in my php.ini file. Anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: learn do use echo to debug, and find where your error is. one i have already found: `while ($row = fetch($data, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))` should be `while ($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`. the `do { .. } while` needs to be removed. just look at the example you posted, its all there

Comment: Please update your question to tell us what you expect to happen, what is happening now, and what you have tried to fix it. Consider including any error messages that you receive, as well as a description of the resources you used to help solve the problem and how they failed to answer your question.

Comment: When I'm running this, it is giving me a 500 Internal Server Error, so I can't see any echoed strings (I get this error even after making the changes you suggested). I have the MDB file in the same directory as my site, just for testing right now as well. And I've updated the question, George!

Comment: Look in the error logs, they will generally have more information about what is causing the error/parse error, etc..

Comment: I've updated the question with what the error log says is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

```
<?php
// Location of database. For some reason I could only get it to work in
// the same location as the site. It's probably an easy fix though
$dbName = "dbName.mdb";
$tName = "table";

// Throws an error if the database cannot be found
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}

// Connects to the database
// Assumes there is no username or password
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName", '', '');

// This is the query
// You have to have each column you select in the format tableName.[ColumnName]
$sql = "SELECT $tName.[ColumnOne], $tName.[ColumnTwo], etc...
        FROM $dbName.$tName";

// Runs the query above in the table
$rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

// This message is displayed if the query has an error in it 
if (!$rs) {
    exit("There is an error in the SQL!");
}

$data = array();
$i = 0;

// Grabs all the rows, saves it in $data
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($rs) ) {
    $data[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
} 

odbc_close($conn); // Closes the connection
$json = json_encode($data); // Generates the JSON, saves it in a variable
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need 1 loop,
fetchAll is your iterable friend:

```
while ($row = $data->fetchAll(SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[] = $row;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

odbc_connect doesn't return an object, it returns a resource.  see (http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php)  so you would need to do something like this.

```
 $db = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName", $user, $password);
 $oexec = obdc_exec($db,$sql);
  $result[] = odbc_fetch_array($oexec);
```

and then you can iterate over results..

see also:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php

Comment: Now this gives me a warning (`odbc_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\\...`) and a fatal error (`Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in C:\\...`)

Comment: Sorry I left out error checking, and the like.  You need to check that all calls don't return false and if they do. call odbc_error to find out what the error is.  My guess is that oexec is false when being passed to obdc_fetch_array.   IN looking at your post, and the tutorial you are following that was using PDO which is different than using the ODBC_* functions

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to get results from an ODBC query into a JSON array:

```
$response = null;
$conn = null;

try {
  $odbc_name = 'myODBC'; //<-ODBC connectyion name as is in the Windows "Data Sources (ODBC) administrator"

  $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM table;";

  $conn = odbc_connect($odbc_name, 'user', 'pass');
  $result = odbc_exec($conn, $sql_query);

  //this will show all results:
  //echo odbc_result_all($result);

  //this will fetch row by row and allows to change column name, format, etc:     
  while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($result) ) { 
     $json['cod_sistema'] = $row['cod_sistema'];
     $json['sistema'] = $row['sistema'];
     $json['cod_subsistema'] = $row['cod_subsistema'];
     $json['sub_sistema'] = $row['sub_sistema'];
     $json['cod_funcion'] = $row['cod_funcion'];
     $json['funcion'] = $row['funcion'];
     $json['func_desc_abrev'] = $row['desc_abreviada'];
     $json['cod_tipo_funcion'] = $row['cod_tipo_funcion'];

     $response[] = array('funcionalidad' => $json);
  }

  odbc_free_result($result); //<- Release used resources

} catch (Exception $e) {
   $response = array('resultado' => 'err', 'detalle' => $e->getMessage());
   echo 'ERROR: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
odbc_close($conn);
return $response;
```

And finnally encoding the response in JSON format:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```